# Waiting for DB creation

Tags: android, database

My app is calling getReadableDatabase but then I am getting a 'Launch timeout has expired - giving up wake lock'.

According to the Android ref guide, it says don't do this call from your main thread beacuse it can be quite slow. I haven't got a database yet, so the onCreate is presumably busy doing that and that is why I am getting the timout?

However, I don't have anything else for my app to do at this point, it has to wait for the DB to be ready before it can continue, so how can I force it to wait for the getReadableDatabase to complete from the main thread?

Or is my error something else (this is it below):

```
10-16 16:00:30.800: INFO/DB Utils(279): In fetchList...
10-16 16:00:39.505: WARN/ActivityManager(58): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
10-16 16:00:39.710: WARN/ActivityManager(58): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{450bce18 co.uk.sanetech.wywh/.TripsScreenActivity}
10-16 16:00:45.034: WARN/ActivityManager(58): Activity destroy timeout for HistoryRecord{44f47ce0 co.uk.sanetech.wywh/.WishYouWereHereActivity}
```

The timeout happens after only about 10 seconds - not sure if that is normal?

Code below:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

   resList = db.query(tabName, null, null, null, null, null, ORDER_BY_LATEST);
```

Any help gratefully appreciated.

Comment: Often writing files (so also databases) it's slow. It's strange that you have to wait 20 seconds only to have a readable database.

Answer (score 2):

> However, I don't have anything else for my app to do at this point, it has to wait for the DB to be ready before it can continue, so how can I force it to wait for the getReadableDatabase to complete from the main thread?

You don't. You do the work (including opening/creating the database) on a background thread. In your UI, display something to indicate that work is going on (e.g., `ProgressBar`, `ProgressDialog`, progress indicator in the title bar). When the work is complete, update your UI to reflect the available data.

Comment: OK, created a thread but now just getting the dreaded 'null pointer exception' and the following stack trace: